# Sed pattern to match and replace

Tags: regex, bash, sed

How can I write a sed expression, which looks through a line to match

`Id   int`

and change to

`Id   string`

this will be the only content in that line (nothing other than, Id int) and should not alter other lines.

I tried with something along the lines

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0  sed -i '' 's~^\([[:space:]]*\)"Id"[[:space:]]*"int"[:space:]]*$~\1"Id string"~g'
```

But the reg exp is wrong.

Thanks.

### Edit:

To clarify further:
There are spaces (inconsistent) before `Id`, between `Id` and `int`. So, needs to match [[:space:]]* , instead of tab or expressions like `s/^Id int$`

so the lines to match can be

```
   Id int
Id   int
  Id      int
```

It can be replaced with

```
Id string
Id string
Id string
```

means, no need to preserve the number of spaces

Comment: Why wouldn't this work?  `sed -i 's/^[ \t]*Id[ \t][ \t]*int[ \t]*$/Id string/'`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah added some clarification. thanks

Comment: Is "Id" literally the two characters "Id", or is it some unknown identifier that you need to preserve in the replacement?

Comment: Id is just 2 char `Id`, not an identifier.

Comment: @bsr My posted solution works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you want:

```
sed 's/^Id int$/Id string'
```

The `^` means *start of the line*, and `$` means *end of the line*, so we restrict the changes to lines which only contain `Id int` and not lines like `I like Id int`.

**Update following OP clarification:**

If you want to match the cases where there is varying whitespace, and preserve this whitespace then you could use:

```
sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*\)Id\([[:space:]]+\)int\([[:space:]]*\)$/\1Id\2string\3/'
```

This will preserve the whitespace before `Id`, between the `Id` and `int`, and after `int`. If you don't want to preserve the whitespace between the words or after thet last word, remove the group match parameters `\2` and `\3` from the `sed` experession.

Comment: well, I have spaces before and after Id. There are spaces between Id and int. All these spaces are not consistent (means can be 1, 2,..).

Answer (score 0):

Easier with awk:

```
awk '$2=="int"{$2="string"}1'
```

And potentially easier to tweak to your actual needs.